# make same space between button in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

i have button in that i want to put same space between all button so if i run app in tablet the space between button will equal divide, i am using linearlayout, i know there is layout_weight option but i don't want to stretch icon

for example [image]

my xml code is below

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shareLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnRequestAPrescriptionRefill"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnYoutube"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwitter"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPintrest"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_pintrest" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use layout_weight. But like you said `Buttons will be stretched`, so instead of using weight on Buttons, use on spaces(Views).

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_facebook" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnYoutube"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_youtube" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwitter"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_twitter" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPintrest"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_pintrest" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Finally your answer is fit :)

Comment: Thank you so much Archie.bpgc

Comment: good answer.  Small improvement: use a <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </Space>
instead of a <View> to make your objective clearer in your XML.

Answer (score 8):

To make your intent clearer in your XML use a `<Space>`  instead of a `<View>` as follows:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <Space
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="1dp"
           android:layout_weight="1" >
       </Space>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:background="@drawable/btn_facebook" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </Space>

...and repeat with the rest of your buttons...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

give `layout_weight` to every `Button` 1, it will divide all space

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_facebook" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnYoutube"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_youtube" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwitter"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_twitter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPintrest"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_pintrest" />
```

Comment: no deepzz i have tried your code but it will look same as layout_weight="1"

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit : Try giving width 0dp instead of wrap_content for those layouts

Answer (score 4):

replace every button with

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_facebook" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i.e. wrap every button with `RelativeLayout` with `android:layout_weight` and `android:gravity`

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a table Layout and have strechColums="0" . Else if you want to stick to linear layout then have you tried out [space](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) .

Comment: Hello Chris can u suggest with strechColumns how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

try this one

Insert Button Here

```
<View
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Insert Button Here